# How to start the Oracle ATG rest webservices and create one?

Tags: oracle, rest, mobile, atg

How to start the Oracle ATG rest webservices and create one .We already have an existing ecom website and now we need to create a mobile app for that using react native and oracle atg.Please help me by providing link to documentation or examples from where to start

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41069_01/Platform.11-0/ATGWSFrameGuide/html/s0201introductiontorestwebservices01.html - Btw I googled...

Answer (score 0):

Oracle ATG has a built-in module for enabling REST services.

The name of the module, the underlying technology, and the method with which you define your own APIs varies depending on the version of ATG you are using.

The best place to start should be the documentation for your ATG version.

Oracle 11 had the first usable framework. It’s clunky, but it works.
See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41069_01/Platform.11-0/ATGWSFrameGuide/html/s0201introductiontorestwebservices01.html.

(Note, prior versions had frameworks for rest services, but they were just repurposed web services frameworks, and quite unusable)

Oracle ATG 11.3 had the first JAX-RS framework, and is quite usable.
See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E69533_01/Platform.11-3/ATGWSFrameGuide/html/s0301partioraclecommerceplatformjaxrs01.html